# youtube api v3 search channels missing results - python

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to search all YouTube channels containing the keyword 'investment' either in their YouTube channel title or description, keep some channel variables and store them in a dataframe. I am using the API v3.

I created the following Python code (that loops over the different page results):

```
def search_channels_with_keyword(youtube, keyword):                      
    
    # Initialize variables for pagination (prepare the loop over YT 50 results x page)
    next_page_token = None
    channels = []                        # store/append results in this list

    while True:
        # Search channels with given keyword in title/description
        search_response = youtube.search().list(
            q=keyword, part='snippet', type='channel', maxResults=50, 
            pageToken=next_page_token                                       
        ).execute()

        # Process the search results
        for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
            channel_id = search_result['id']['channelId']
            channel_title = search_result['snippet']['title']
            channel_description = search_result['snippet']['description']
            channel_thumbnailurl = item['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url']
            channels.append({                                                          # Append vars in list 'channels'
                'channel_id': channel_id,
                'channel_title': channel_title,
                'channel_description': channel_description,
                'channel_thumbnailurl': channel_thumbnailurl
            })
            
        # Check if more pages to fetch
        next_page_token = search_response.get('nextPageToken')
        if not next_page_token:
            break                                   # Exit the loop if no more pages

    return channels

if __name__ == "__main__":
    keyword = 'investment'                             
    channels = search_channels_with_keyword(youtube, keyword)

    # Store results in pandas df
    df_channels = pd.DataFrame(channels)
    df_channels
```

The above code provides some ok output (584 channels with the desired keyword 'investment'), but few manual checks let me know this is definitely not a comprehensive list. For instance, it does not provide [this](https://www.youtube.com/@PatrickWieland/about) YT channel with +200k subscribers.

I am afraid I am missing out a lot of (important) channels. Is it an issue with the API? with my code?

Thanks all in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem that can't be solved with use API v3...

I also have the same problem; I tried reduce sampling by `published date`, but the result of searching was always around 550-590.

For example; I tried to find videos for one day and one month and result was the same.